# How do I use find_all or select more precisely in this case?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I run the following code after importing stuff:

```
Fighter1Main = []
for i in range(1,3):
            url = Request(f"https://www.sherdog.com/events/a-{page}", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            response = urlopen(url).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            for test2 in soup.find_all(class_="fighter left_side"):
                test3 = test2.find_all(itemprop="url")
                Fighter1Main.append(test3)
            page = page + 1
```

I get:

```
[[<a href="/fighter/Todd-Medina-61" itemprop="url">
<img alt="Todd 'El Tiburon' Medina" itemprop="image" src="/image_crop/200/300/_images/fighter/20140801074225_IMG_5098.JPG" title="Todd 'El Tiburon' Medina">
</img></a>], [<a href="/fighter/Ricco-Rodriguez-8" itemprop="url">
<img alt="Ricco 'Suave' Rodriguez" itemprop="image" src="/image_crop/200/300/_images/fighter/20141225125221_1MG_9472.JPG" title="Ricco 'Suave' Rodriguez">
</img></a>]]
```

But I was expecting:

```
<a href="/fighter/Todd-Medina-61" itemprop="url">
<a href="/fighter/Ricco-Rodriguez-8" itemprop="url">
```

This is the type of webpage in question https://www.sherdog.com/events/a-1

I also tried using css select and got the same result.

```
for test2 in soup.select('.fighter.left_side [itemprop="url"]'):
                Fighter1Main.append(test2)
```

I thought I was using it correctly but I'm not sure how else to narrow it down to what I want.

Comment: I guess, seeing from your returned list, that the itemprop="url" is part of your a tag. Perhaps you can try to just do something like ```test2.find_all('a', href=True)``` or ```test2.find_all('a')```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is that you're getting a list of lists, and you just want a flat list, then you should do it like

```py
            for test2 in soup.find_all(class_="fighter left_side"): 
                Fighter1Main += [t for t in test2.find_all(itemprop="url")]
```

but since you weren't happy with the output from *`for test2 in soup.select('.fighter.left_side [itemprop="url"]'): Fighter1Main.append(test2)`*, and from your title, I'm guessing that isn't the the problem here.

---

If you want to filter out any tags that have a nested tag inside them then you can add `:not(:has(*))` to your selector

```py
            for test2 in soup.select('.fighter.left_side *[itemprop="url"]:not(:has(*))'): 
                Fighter1Main.append(test2)
```

however, you can **expect an empty list** if you do this because [as far as I can tell] all tags matched to `.fighter.left_side *[itemprop="url"]` *will* have an `img` tag nested within.

---

---

If you *really* want something like your expected output, you'll have to either alter the `soup` or build it up yourself.

---

You can either remove everything inside the Tags with `itemprop="url"` [original `soup` object will be altered]:

```py
            for test2 in soup.select('.fighter.left_side *[itemprop="url"]'): 
                test2.clear()
                Fighter1Main.append(test2)
```

---

Or you could form new html tags with only the `href` [if there is any] and `itemprop` attributes [original `soup` object will remain unaltered, but you'll be parsing and extracting again for each item]:

```py
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            Fighter1Main += [BeautifulSoup(
                f'<{n}{h} itemprop="url"></{n}>', "html.parser"
            ).find(n) for n, h in [(
                t.name, '' if t.get("href") is None else f' href="{t.get("href")}"'
            ) for t in soup.select('.fighter.left_side *[itemprop="url"]')]]
```